# How to get value of a <td> onclick to an other <td> of a same row?

Tags: javascript, html

The fiddle is available here :

https://jsfiddle.net/syLuLob0/71/

As you can see , there is a listener of the 3rd column of the table. I would like to get the value of the 2nd column's td on click of the 3rd column cell.

For instance, if I click to "dead" the value will be "1047" and if I click to "ok" , the value will be "1048".

I did this function:

```
function showStatusDialog(){  
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      alert(document.getElementById("TR"+i).childNodes[1].innerHTML);
     }
}
```

It's displaying all the values..

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first grab the parenNode then access the previous sibling by looking at the parents childNodes.  then parse out an int from the sibling textContent property.

you can do it like so by changing your showStatusDialog function (the clickhandler):

```
function showStatusDialog(){  
    var sibling = this.parentNode.childNodes[1];
    var value = parseInt(sibling.textContent);
    console.log(value);
    //alert(document.getElementById("TR"+0).childNodes[1].innerHTML);

}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/syLuLob0/79/)

Answer (score 1):

you use jQuery selector to get the prev td value and parse the string

```
parseInt($(this).prev('td').text())
```

https://jsfiddle.net/syLuLob0/78/

Comment: Although it's a good suggestion - the OP hasn't mentioned anything about using jQuery

Comment: As it was a added library on jsFiddle I assumed that this would be acceptable